# bash switch-case statement gives syntax error

Tags: bash, switch-statement

```
#!/bin/bash
```

echo "Title: "
read title
echo ""
until [ -n "$title" ]
do
    echo "Please enter title: "
    read title
    echo ""
done
echo "Author: "
read author
echo ""
until [ -n "$author" ]
do
    echo "Please enter author: "
    read author
    echo ""
done

check=`cat ./BookDB.txt | egrep -ie "\b""$title""\b" | egrep -ie "\b""$author""\b"`
if [ -z "$check" ]
then
    echo "Error! Book does not exist!"
    #need some code to continue
else
    echo "Book found!"
    all=`cat ./BookDB.txt | grep -i "$title"`

```
oldtitle=`echo "$all" | cut -d ":" -f1`
oldauthor=`echo "$all" | cut -d ":" -f2`
oldprice=`echo "$all" | cut -d ":" -f3`
oldavail=`echo "$all" | cut -d ":" -f4`
oldsold=`echo "$all" | cut -d ":" -f5`
```

fi
    while :
    do
     echo ""
        echo "  a) Update title"
        echo "  b) Update author"
        echo "  c) Update price"
        echo "  d) Update quantity available"
        echo "  e) Update quantity sold"
        echo "  f) Back to main menu"
        echo ""
        echo -n "Please enter your choice: "
        read option

`` case $option in 
    a ) 
        echo -n "New title: "
        read newtitle
        if [ "$oldtitle" = "$newtitle" ]
        then
        echo "Title is the same as original"
        else
        all_title=`cut -f 1 -d ":" ./BookDB.txt`
        check=`echo "$all_title" | grep -i "\b""$newtitle""\b"`
        fi
            if [ -n "$check" ]
            then
            echo "Book title already exists."
            else
            sed -i "s/$oldtitle:/$newtitle:/g" ./BookDB.txt
            echo "Book title successfully updated."

        fi

b ) 


esac
done ``

i can't run this code on bash. they say there is a syntax error at my CASE selection at this line 
b )

which i see no problem at all

Comment: try to slim down the problem... create a minimal example...

Comment: `all=cat ./BookDB.txt | grep -i "$title"` is very suspect.  Nothing to do with the `case` missing `;;`, but I think you mean: `all=$(grep -i "$title" ./BookDB.txt)`.  There is another larger example above that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using case statements, you need to end each clause with `;;`:

```
case $option in 
    a )
        # do something
        ;;
    b )
        # do something
        ;;
esac
```

you can read [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) for more details on the case statement.

Comment: its correct! thank you so much on that link for the guide